# PyTorch find keypoints: output nodes to be in a range and negative loss

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am beginner in deep learning.
I am using this [dataset](https://handtracker.mpi-inf.mpg.de/projects/GANeratedHands/GANeratedDataset.htm) and I want my network to detect keypoints of a hand.

How can I make my output layer's nodes to be in range [-1, 1] (range of normalized 2D points)?
Another problem is when I train for more than 1 epoch the loss gets negative values

criterion: *torch.nn.MultiLabelSoftMarginLoss()* and optimizer: *torch.optim.SGD()*

[Here](https://github.com/iBraven/SummerPractice/blob/master/nnTrain.py) u can find my repo

```
net = nnModel.Net()
net = net.to(device)
criterion = nn.MultiLabelSoftMarginLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ExponentialLR(optimizer=optimizer, gamma=decay_rate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Tanh](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Tanh.html) activation function, since the image of the function lies in [-1, 1].

The problem of predicting key-points in an image is more of a regression problem than a classification problem (especially if you're making your model outputs + targets fall within a continuous interval). Therefore, I suggest you use the [L2 Loss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MSELoss.html#torch.nn.MSELoss).

In fact, it could be a good exercise for you to determine which loss function that is appropriate for regression problems provides the lowest expected generalization error using cross-validation. There's several such functions available in PyTorch.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is to use `torch.nn.Sigmoid` which produces outputs in [0,1] range and scale outputs to [-1,1] using `2*x-1` transformation.